# Position of superscript when superscriptd item has \hat over it

Tags: math-mode, positioning, superscripts

I am trying to typeset he following inline math for a camera-ready document:

```
$\hat{\boldsymbol \Sigma}_{P}^{-1} \hat{\boldsymbol \Sigma}_{G}$
```

It appears that the superscript -1 is aligned considering \Sigma and the \hat symbol as  complete item. This increases the line spacing. What I would like to typeset is the -1 aligned with \Sigma only, i.e. to move it downward a little. Is that feasible and, if so, how can this done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick hack is to insert `{}` before the subscript and superscript. Then, `_{P}^{-1}` are sub- and super-script of `{}`, which has the right size.

```
$\hat{\boldsymbol \Sigma}{}_{P}^{-1} \hat{\boldsymbol \Sigma}_{G}$
```

Comment: +1 A similar option is to smash the box: `$\smash{\hat{\boldsymbol \Sigma}}_{P}^{-1}`

Comment: Many thanks for the prompt replies - adding {} works beautifully; I love a simple solution!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whay you want. But in my opinion you want to produce something like this:

```
$\widehat{\boldsymbol \Sigma_{P}^{-1}}$
```

In this case you simply places the entire sigma with its sub and subscript under a hat. If thats not the case you can use:

```
$\widehat{\boldsymbol \Sigma}{}_{P}^{-1}$
```

I suggest using \widehat and not just \hat. Because if you use large symbols or more than one character under the hat. It will give som strange results.

Comment: +1 for `\widehat`