# superscript issue in latex

Tags: tex-core, superscripts

I have 2 superscripts in 1 equation but one of these is floating higher than the other making it look messy. The code I have used is:

```
 $\hat{\boldsymbol\beta}^T X^T$
```

The T is higher for the beta as the hat on top is forcing it higher:
[image: The two superscripts are not lined up nicely.]

Is there any way of forcing the T back down to the normal superscript height?

[Full minimal example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\hat{\boldsymbol\beta}^T X^T$
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this Tex.SX answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9184/position-of-superscript-when-superscriptd-item-has-hat-over-it), we can put `{}` between the super- and other-scripts:

```
$\hat{\boldsymbol\beta}{}^T X^T$
```

This'll line things up:

[image: Lined up correctly.]